# Migrating from "native GWT" to GXT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am thinking of migrating my GWT app from "native GWT" to GXT, however I want to know whether  there is a theme in GXT that looks just like the native theme of GWT, `com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard`

Also in my "native GWT" application I apply my own css to some widgets. Does the CSS-format for widgets the same with GXT as it is with the native GWT widgets? Like for Button, MenuBar, Panels etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically GXT 2 has just two themes (blue and gray). There is no such a theme that looks like native GWT, but thats why you should choose GXT, becuose  it has rich components and you don't have to take care of your css and other stuffs. Also is not easy to change you style.

> Ext GWT 2.0, widgets are responsible for creating their DOM structure
>   directly. This is done either by manually creating the elements or by
>   using an HTML fragment. The HTML for the widget is created from
>   strings, from an XTemplate, or by assembling DOM elements. The CSS
>   class names are then applied to the elements by the widgets. With this
>   approach, a widget’s view is tightly bound to the widget itself and
>   CSS class names are generally hardcoded into the widget.

Because the way how was build is really difficult to change the style of your component. But the new version 3.0 has a new approach that make easier to change your style and you can also combine with native gwt widget.

You can check the [website](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-appearance-design/)

Comment: It is possible to do it in 2.0. With 3.0 is gonna be easier